# At least two are not yellow probability

Tags: probability

So the problem is the following, 
There are 11 birds ,  6 are yellow , 3 are green and two are blue. We randomly form a group of 5 birds taken from these 11 birds. What is the probability that 2 or more are not yellow?

I did some kind of a research and computed it like this however i am not sure if it is correct : 
p("2 or more are not yellow ")= 1-(6 choose 4)/(11choose 5)

Could you please give a feedback to my solutions or help me to solve ? thank you in advance

edit:
Whould it be right if i would : 1- (possibility there are 4 yellow)+(possibility there are 5 yellow)? ?

Comment: It would help if you included the "thinking process" and thoughts and work that lead to your answer.

Comment: Hint:  there are two ways to fail this test.  Either all the five are yellow or exactly four out of the five are yellow.

Comment: Use this formula:

$$P(\text{at least } x)=1-P\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{x-1}P(n)\bigg).$$ By "sum" I mean "intersection", so $P(0)\cap P(1)\cap \cdots P(n)$, but personally, I've always found it easier to think of it as sum.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format the question. Also show us your efforts on the problem to avoid this question being highly downvoted or being closed. See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults) link to know how to ask a good question on this website

Comment: Whould it be right if i would : 1- (possibility there are 4 yellow)+(possibility there are 5 yellow)?